# Using CryptoJS to encrypt and Aes Manager to decrypt

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I am using CryptoJS to encrypt a message and send it to the server, and decrypting it on the other end in C# using Aes Manager. I get a response back when I send it to the server, but it isn't correct.

Javascript:

```
this.CryptoJS=require("crypto-js");
var temp=this.CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("hello","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyykey",{
  keySize:128/8,
  iv:this.CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("helllooohelllooo"),
  mode:this.CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  padding:this.CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
});
data.text=temp.toString(); // This is how I send it to the server
```

C#:

```
byte[] Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyykey");
byte[] toBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("helllooohelllooo");
AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();
aes.Key = Key;
aes.IV = toBytes;
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
aes.KeySize = 128;
aes.BlockSize = 128;
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data.text);
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
{
    MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    CryptoStream CS = new CryptoStream(MS, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    CS.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    CS.FlushFinalBlock();
    MS.Position = 0;
    bytes = new byte[MS.Length];
    MS.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    Plaintext = utf8.GetString(bytes);
    var temp = 5;
}
```

This is what I get as a result from the `Plaintext` variable: ``` t�k�\a``\u007f��Ü����\f^,F~\u0017�\u001fp��#5�\u007f\\ ```

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly pass the key, plaintext and IV as binary data rather than strings:

```
let iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("helllooohelllooo");
let pt = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("hello");
let key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyykey");
```

Then use in the code like so:

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(pt, key, ...);
```

Note that your use of zero padding, fixed IV, and no HMAC or AEAD mode makes the code you have completely insecure.  You definitely should not use it.  Consult [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) for examples of secure encryption between JavaScript and C#.

Comment: The problem with AES-GCM is it's unavailability on some popular platforms.

Comment: Once I added the code above it changed them into wordArrays and i dont know how to accept them on the C# side of things

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem i was not converting the original key to utf8 and once i did that it fixed itself

[Resource](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/47800a60-4461-4f8e-a8d1-751fa62c7884/aes-encrypt-in-javascript-and-decrypt-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)